# How to add other users as friends?

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables. The first table is Requests and it looks like this

```
+------------------------------+
|          Requests            |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id |  user_from  |  user_to  |
+----+-------------+-----------+
|    |             |           |
|    |             |           |
|    |             |           |
|    |             |           |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

When the request has been sent and the other user has accepted, they get moved from the requests table into the friends table, knowing that they now are indeed friends.

And here is my friends table:

```
+--------------------------------+
|            Friends             |
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id |   user_id   |  friend_id  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|    |             |             |
|    |             |             |
|    |             |             |
|    |             |             |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

Now my question to you is, how do I "move" (once the request is accepted) the data from the requests table to the friends table?

And how will the SQL query look if I want to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INSERT INTO` query followed by a `DELETE FROM` query? If you have `Requests.id`, something like

```
INSERT INTO Friends (user_id, friend_id) SELECT Requests.user_id, Requests.friend_id FROM Requests WHERE Requests.id = $Your_ID;
DELETE FROM Requests where id = $Your_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL has no 'move' command. There's only insert and delete. You'd want to use a transaction for this:

```
start transaction;
insert into friends ...
delete from requests ...
commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not "move" it at all. You INSERT into one, and DELETE from the other. Do it in a transaction to be sure it happens atomically.

Answer (score 1):

Add another coolumn called  `accepted` which is initially false.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|            Friends                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+
| id |   user_id   |  friend_id  | accepted |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+
|    |             |             |          |
|    |             |             |          |
|    |             |             |          |
|    |             |             |          |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Now you don't need to move anything - you just update the field to `TRUE`.

Comment: Oh ok! I presume it's just as effective as the other manner??

Answer (score 0):

> HOW DO I "MOVE" (once the request is accepted) THE DATA FROM THE
>   REQUESTS TABLE TO THE FRIENDS TABLE???

By doing a DELETE on the request table and an INSERT in the friends table. Actually, you'll probably want to do *two* inserts with the roles reversed in order to make queries more simple.